# Google Search Console error with path to sitemap.xml

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

I have site-shop and the platform created a *sitemap.xml* automatically. But in Google Search Console  there is an error because robots.txt like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my/
Disallow: /cart/
Disallow: /checkout/
Sitemap: sumki5.ru/sitemap-shop.xml
Crawl-delay: 5

User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /my/
Disallow: /cart/
Disallow: /checkout/
Crawl-delay: 5
Sitemap: sumki5.ru/sitemap-shop.xml
Host: sumki5.ru
```

Is this normal? Can it be a problem for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sitemap URL *has* to be absolute.   In your case it is missing the `https://`.   Change the line to:

```
Sitemap: https://sumki5.ru/sitemap-shop.xml
```

And Google will stop complaining in search console.

If you don't fix the problem, Google will not be able to access your sitemap.  That isn't necessarily a disaster.   Sitemap files are not needed for good SEO.  In fact, they really don't help at all.  What they do is give you additional insight into your site in Google Search Console.  See: [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: It could be HTTP too. Right? Or am I missing something? Cheers!!

Comment: I checked their site and they redirect HTTP to HTTPS, so I put in HTTPS in this case.

Comment: I am missing something! Not too sharp right now... distracted. Cheers!!